# Websockets for non-realtime apps?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have been studying web sockets recently and plan to use them in my application even though the app is not realtime. I am mostly doing this because I want to try it out and further down the line it might open more possibilites for the app's functionality. Also I am not bothered about having an API for mobile at the moment but think it would still be possible to have some kind of api over web sockets if I needed it in the future.

**However for in-production apps are there any real reasons why somebody would consider implementing websockets if there is no real-time element?**

Are there any benefits over HTTP requests other than the real timeness of it?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requests include the full HTTP headers. Depending on the cookie load, this may reach a couple of KB per request. WebSocket protocol headers are minimal compared to that. If you have a lot of requests and care about bandwidth then going with WebSocket makes sense.

Additionally a HTTP connection is (traditionally) negotiated for each request, which means you have overhead on each request compared to WebSocket, which has persistent connections. Connection establishment takes time (hence the advantage in real-time applications), but it also uses resources on the server. Again, depending on your app's communication patterns, using WebSocket may make sense.